# Grails 2.5 died at startup after a while : "parent process shutdown"

Tags: grails

I want to test Grails 2.5.0 with JDK 1.8.
So under DOS, as usual, I created an application then I tried to launch it.
It takes 15 minutes before died !

Here is the output :

```
grails create-app thecoder
| Created Grails Application at C:\Users\drieu\workspace_grails\thecoder

grails run-app

| Compiling 10 source files

| Compiling 117 source files
Note: C:\Users\drieu\workspace_grails\thecoder\target\work\plugins\scaffolding-2
.1.2\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\scaffolding  \AbstractGrailsTemplateGener
ator.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
| Running Grails application
|Parent process shutdown. Exiting...
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

I tried also to run with stacktrace and verbose option but without success :

```
C:\Users\drieu\workspace_grails\toto>grails run-app -stacktrace -verbose
Base Directory: C:\Users\drieu\workspace_grails\toto
| Compiling 1 source files
 [groovyc] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\drieu\workspace_grails\toto\targ
| Running Grails application 
|Parent process shutdown. Exiting...
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Other informations :

- Java version : JDK 1.8.0_45
- Grails : 2.5.0
- Windows : 8.1

Comment: please add the usual `--info --debug --stacktrace` barrage

Comment: if you run with debugging, then it expects of you, that an debugger attaches to that port.

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will search how we attach a debugger